# How to show 2 Maps in 1 application at same time using Fragments

Tags: android

My problem is I have to run 2 different maps at the same time in same application. Both maps will be visible at same time. I am working on Android 3.2 and using Fragments.

I know "Only one MapActivity is supported per process. Multiple MapActivities running simultaneously are likely to interfere in unexpected and undesired ways." I also checked  discussions of running activity in different process with android:process tag. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3756#c7

Currently, I am creating an Activity with two fragments and each fragment contains a TabHost. Each TabHost contains a map activity.

Though I have specified process of each MapActivity but I still get RecyclingMapObject error in Logcat and same map object is reused. Kindly suggest if we can any workaround so that 2 Maps can be displayed at the same time.

Sample source code used from  https://github.com/inazaruk/examples/tree/master/MapFragmentExample.

Thanks & Regards,
Vibhor